# make array if an element of array matched the

Tags: php, arrays

How to break an array in an array if an element like xyz value having same values mark or admon. I want an array the have only abc value if for the array

Make array of elements having same value

```
    Array
        (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [abc] => 1586
                [xyz] => mark
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [abc] => 123456
                [xyz] => mark
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [abc] => 235689
                [xyz] => Admon
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [abc] => 12564
                [xyz] => Admon
            )

        )
```

Resultant array should be look like this

```
Array
        (
        [0] => (
                [abc] => 1586,123456
                [xyz] = mark
            )

        [1] => (
                [abc] => 235689,12564
                [xyz] => admon
            )

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the original array to match criteria like like mark or admon

```
$new = [];
$unik = array_unique(array_column((array)$original, 'xyz'));

$new = array_map(function($a) use ($original){
  $c = array_filter($original, function($f){ return $a == $f['xyz'] });
  $k = array_column($c, 'abc')
  return implode(',', $k);
}, $unik);
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @user1252087 just cast to be an array, put <code>(array)</code>in front of original array. like `(array)$original`

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    $temp[$obj->xyz][] = $obj->abc;
}
$result = array();
foreach ($temp as $arr => $value) {
    $result[] = array('abc' => implode(',', $value), 'xyz' => $arr);
}
print_r($result);
```